# Specifying the first character in an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an input field with a place holder.

```
<input id="showInfo" type="text" placeholder="Search product" />
```

I'm allowing to search a product by its code. Every product begins with `S`. example: S12548, S25487, S87425

How can I make sure the first character is `S` when the `keypress()` function is fired?

```
$('#search').keypress(function(e){

});
```

Comment: Try the demo from jquery [.keypress() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `indexOf()` to check if the first character of the typed string is `s` or `S`.

```
$('#search').keypress(function (e) {
    var text = $(this).val().trim();

    if (text.indexOf('S') === 0 || text.indexOf('s') === 0) {
        // Valid
    } else {
        // Invalid, then add a at the start
        $(this).val('S' + text);
    }
});
```

**Demo** using Regular Expression.

You can also use regex to check if the string starts with `s/S`

```js
$('#search').keyup(function(e) {
  var text = $(this).val().trim();

  $(this).toggleClass('error', !/^s/i.test(text));
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" />
```

You can also use `regex` to check if text starts with `s`.

```
if (/^s/i.test(text)) {
    // Valid
```

Comment: Looks good. But this only checks if the first character is `S`. I'm looking for a away to add `S` if it's not in the string?

Comment: Look great :) I prefer your previous answer with the if statements. That suites perfectly my requirement. Would you please post that as well.

Comment: @Becky Was removed by mistake. I've added it again

Comment: Can this line `if (text.indexOf('S') === 0 || text.indexOf('s') === 0) {` be written as `if (text.indexOf('S') != 0 || text.indexOf('s') != 0) {` to get the opposite meaning?

Comment: @Becky Use `&&` instead of `||` :)

Comment: Thanks. So `!= 0` is correct?  `if (text.indexOf('S') != 0 && text.indexOf('s') != 0) { $(this).val('S' + text); }`

Comment: @Becky Yes, it is correct, you can also use `regex` approach

Comment: I would suggest to use `input` event instead of `keypress`, `keyup`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check on blur of the input try this code and hit right if you like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#showInfo").blur(function () {
        var is_s = $(this).val();
        if (is_s.charAt(0) == 's' || is_s.charAt(0) == 'S') {
            alert("Check for prod");
        } else {
            alert("Do not check for prod");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna think about something like this:

```
if ([ID].charAt(0) == 's' || [ID].charAt(0) == 'S') {
    return;
} else {
    [ID].insert(0, s);
}
```

Comment: Don't add pseudo-elements in code while answering, use real variables

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
$('#search').keypress(function (e) {
    var text = $(this).text().trim();

    if (text.charAt(0).toLowerCase() == 's') {
        // Condition True  - Do Something
    } else {
        // Condition False - Do something
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyCode to check if it 'S''

```
$('#search').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 83) {
     // continue ...
  }
}
```

Comment: yes that right, also about your issue if you do search in backend you should re-test if your search term start with 'S'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery use [jQuery Validator plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and something like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("searchCode", function(value, element) {
    var aux = $('#search').value;
    return aux.charAt(0) == "S";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#showInfo').keyup(function(e) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value.substring(0, 1) != 's') {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid #ff0000');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```